# Debug and View Registers

Tags: stm32, embedded, debugging, eclipse, stm32cubeide

I would like to view and analyze the registers in STM32 Embedded Cards(For Ex. STM32F407DISK) in STM32CubeIDE.

As far as I know from the user manual and my own experience in CubeIDE, I did see my expressions in the Live Expression section in Debug Perspective but not Registers. I can not see the register values as in the Live Expression section. I have to suspend the debug mode to see the values in registers.

By the way, I don't want to see a specific register to write it in Live Expression. Is there any way to see all the registers live?

Comment: The various Eclipse debuggers might be the worst ever made since the dawn of computing. Consider using another tool chain for that reason alone.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry your question has gone for 2 months unanswered.  I just solved this issue myself so I figured I'd swing by with my findings.  If anyone else more experienced chimes in, prefer their advice over mine lol

In STM32CubeIDE, look for the SFRs pane.  If you set up your project with the CubeMX tool, this pane should have the addresses of all the registers.

In my case, I was looking for the register that controlled the on-board LED on a NUCLEO, which I knew from the datasheed was GPIO G, Pin 13 on my device.  According to the datasheet of the processor (not the demo board), the register should be at 0x40021800 + an offset (which you can calculate with the table in the processor datasheet)

Run your code in debug mode and step through it.  Once you reach line that will change the value of your desired register, go to the SFRs tab, expand the item you want to see on the registers (in my case GPIOG) and look for your register (in my case the ODR register).

You can even see the individual bits in that register if you don't want to do the hexadecimal math in your head:

[image]